# bash loop to execute command on last file only

Tags: linux, bash, file, for-loop, sed

I have used `split` to split a +6m rows csv file and covert it to tsv with `sed`. All worked wonderfully, I only need to get rid of the last line of the last file (files have alphabetically descending extensions thanks to `split`).

Here's my file structure.

```
├── persons-with-significant-control-snapshot-2019-03-13.txt
├── psc_aa
├── psc_aa.csv
├── psc_aa.csv.tsv
├── psc_ab
├── psc_ab.csv
├── psc_ab.csv.tsv
├── psc_ac
├── psc_ac.csv
├── psc_ac.csv.tsv
├── psc_ad
├── psc_ad.csv
├── psc_ad.csv.tsv
├── psc_ae
├── psc_ae.csv
├── psc_ae.csv.tsv
├── psc_af
├── psc_af.csv
├── psc_af.csv.tsv
├── psc_ag
├── psc_ag.csv
└── psc_ag.csv.tsv
```

I know that the last line of the last file is systematically broken after being converted to tsv - now here's the issue: I know how to eliminate the last line **when I know the file name, but when I don't?**:

`sed -i '$d' psc_ag.csv.tsv`

But ideally this mini pipeline will be running automatically, so depending on what the names of the `split` programme will be, this sed might change.

In pseudo code I'd need something like this:

```
for file in psc_*.csv.tsv
if iterating on last_file
do sed -i '$d' last_file
```

Comment: `for file in psc_*.csv.tsv; do : do something here; done; sed -i '$d' "$file"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this fairly simply with bash arrays:

```
#use globbing to get a list of files into an array (note
#  globs return in alpha-numeric order by default  
files=( psc_*.csv.tsv )

last_file="${files[-1]}"

#loop through everything except last entry:
for file in "${files[@]::${#files[@]}-1}" do
    ...
done

#handle last entry:
sed -i '$d' $last_file
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
find [PATH] -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -n | cut -d " " -f2 | tail -n 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using *GNU* `sed`:

```
sed -i '$d' psc_*.csv.tsv
```

Note: this method is inefficient, since it makes `sed` read through every file.

Comment: Isn't this going to delete the last line from every file following the pattern `psc_*.csv.tsv`?

Comment: @TytireRecubans, No, it'll delete *only* the last line from the last file.  If in doubt, in `bash` try this: `sed '$d' <(printf '%s\n' {a..d}) <(seq 4)`